# Leave Swing JMenuBar tree open after selecting certain elements

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I am currently in the process of self-teaching myself Java through the very comprehensive and readable text by Horstmann and Cornell published by Sun (8th ed/Vol 1. ISBN: 978-0-12-235476-9) and through completing one of the Swing examples (Listing 9-8) I noticed an annoying action performed upon selecting "Toggle" menu items.

The example shows toggling between certain options using the `JCheckBoxMenuItem` and `JRadioButtonMenuItem` classes. I noticed that upon selection of one of those menu components, the entire tree traversed closes. Is there a way to stop this menu closing through either a settable property of the items, or a method called in the `ActionListener` provided?

Link to authors code dump: [Here](http://horstmann.com/corejava/corejava8.zip)

Cheers for any response. Would be a nice tweak to chuck into UI implementation further down the line.

Answer (score 2):

- [not possible from Java6](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/combo-box-no-action/), for `JPopup` used for `JMenu` and `JComboBox`, popup is hidden from mouse a keyboar events
- could be possible for custom popup for `JMenu`/`JComboBox` based on (undecorated) `JDialog` or `JWindow`, with JButtons (in your case with `JCheckBox`/`JRadioButtons`) layed by `GridLayout`

Comment: So basically one way is to almost implement my own menu system where consecutive windows are born from that above it, and act like menu's should? Sounds like I got more than I bargained for here.

Surely there would be a way to call a method which unfolds a tree to a certain menu entity. Not quite keeping it open, rather closing it, then reopening it in sub-millisecond time.